# Find duplicate objects in list when grouping on one or more fields

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, linq, optimization, data-structures

I need to find all objects in a list that intersect with at least one other object in the list. This is determined from a few settings:

1. A list of "duplicate check" fields (e.g. a Person can intersect on `FirstName`, `LastName`, or `DOB`).
2. The minimum number of fields which must be equal for two Persons to intersect (e.g. if the number is 2, Person A and Person B would intersect if they have either the same `FirstName` and `LastName`, the same `FirstName` and `DOB`, or the same `LastName` and `DOB`).

What is the most efficient way to determine this? Right now, using SQL and temp tables with `GROUP BY` statements is most performant, but not good enough. I tried using dictionaries and hardcoding various property checks in C#/LINQ, but that is even worse. I've been looking into disjoint sets and Levenshtein distance, but that seems just as inefficient for a large list. Is this just an NP Complete problem?

Comment: Have any sample data to play with?

Comment: You should always use a rdbms tag, sql server, mysql, etc

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your table using [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to this format

If you dont have `user_id` you could create one using `row_number()`

```
 USER_ID, FIELDNAME  , VALUE
   1    , "LastName" , "Smith"
   1    , "FirstName", "Jhon"
   1    , "DOB"      , "15/09/48"
```

Then perfom this join

```
SELECT T1.user_id, T2.user_id, count(T2.FieldName)
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table1 T2
  on T1.UserID > T2.UserID
 and T1.FIELDNAME = T2.FIELDNAME
 and T1.Value = T2.Value
GROUP BY T1.user_id, T2.user_id
HAVING count(T2.FieldName)  >= 2
```

Comment: I change `<>` to `>` to avoid repeat / reverse pairing.

Comment: I'll have to take a closer look tomorrow but this looks like a definite step in the right direction!

Comment: As long you can handle UNPIVOT this should be easy.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the second query/join you posted does not run in a reasonable amount of time (didn't finish after 7+ minutes and tempdb ran out of space). I even added indexes on all three columns of the UNPIVOT'ed table.

Comment: @bmay2 how big is your table?

Comment: Can you include a explain/analyze from your query?